# How to add the images array to WooCommerce Product Creation using Make (formerly Integromat)?

Tags: woocommerce, make.com, integromat-apps

What should the array of objects look like in order to add images to a WooCommerce product?
I'm used two variants:

```
[
 {
    "src": "url",
    "position": 0
 }
]
```

and

```
[
 {
    "src": "url"
 }
]
```

but received an error:

```
BundleValidationError
Validation failed for 1 parameter(s).
Array of objects expected in parameter 'images'.
```

anyone have some expertise?

I want to get a valid array so that adding pictures to the newly created product will work.